# Trouble with meta login

Tags: support, status-norepro

I am having trouble with meta.movies.stackexchange.com. It won't do automagical login and does not let me login the usual way either. Clicking login simply reloads the page without logging me in.

If I however go to https://meta.movies.stackexchange.com manually (the https page), it works and I am instantly logged in.

I am using the latest Chromium.

Any idea whats going on? What is the usual behaviour? Does it send you to the https page when you click login?

Comment: I'm using Chrome ... it doesn't send me to the HTTPS page (I don't think, lol). I haven't had any issues logging in.

Comment: Does this issue still exist?

Comment: Don't think so.